# how to for...in loop in async.waterfall nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have an object

```
var object = {
 name : null,
 id : 12,
 sys : [{name:'sys'}],
 info : 'string',
 some : [{name:'some'}],
 end : null
}
```

in nodejs I need to find in this object arrays and then stringfy and send to redis. So I search array

```
for(var key in object){
 if(Array.isArray(object[key])) {
  async.waterfall([
   function(callback) {
    // put finded item to redis, then from redis I need to get the key.
   },
   function(res, body, callback) {
    if(body) {
     object[key] = body // I need to replace array > key.
    }
   }
  ])
 }
}
```

But It's async, so in second function `object[key]` is not the same `object[key]` in previous function. For example in first function of waterfall I put `object[key]` = sys into redis, then I wait for the key, and in second function when I get the key `object[key]` = name. How can I past key to correct object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a bit different approach

```
var keys = [];
// get the keys that refers to array property
for(var key in object) { 
    if(Array.isArray(object[key])) keys.push(key);
}

async.forEachSeries(keys, function(key, next){
    // use object[key] 
    // Do the redis thing here and in it's callback function call next
    ........, function(){
        object[key] = body;
        next();
    });
});
```

**Update**
Just realised there's no reason for series, forEach should work as well.

```
async.forEach(keys, function(key, next){
    // use object[key] 
    // Do the redis thing here and in it's callback function call next
    ........, function(){
        object[key] = body;
        next();
    });
}, function(err){ console.log('done'); });
```